# Why is `merge()` producing an empty object?

Tags: r, merge, subset

I have subset a data frame by species using `which()`:

`sp1 <- data[which(data$species=='sp1'),]`

There are data for 4 sites in this subset data frame (`sp1`), and I would like to pull out the data from two of them and combine them into a a new data frame.

I subset them out using `which()` again:

`site.1 <- data.frame(sp1[which(sp1$site=='site1'),])
site.2 <- data.frame(sp1[which(sp1$site=='site2'),])`

However, when I use `merge()` to combine them into a new data frame:

`site.1.2 <- merge(site.1,site.2, by = "site")`

R produces an empty data frame (with the correct headers).

My questions are:

1) Why isn't `merge()` putting the data from `site.1` and `site.2` into this new data frame?

2) Could I simply subset the data from site1 and site2 out of the original data frame together? If so, how? I have tried to use `which()` with an OR statement:

`site.1.2 <- data.frame(data[which(data$site=='site1'),] | data[which(data$site=='site1'),])`

but this was not successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

merge isn't working because it is looking to match site being equal in the two data sets, you could do it by doing it `by = "all other columns"` maybe

the easiest way to do what you want would be

```
site.1.2 <- sp1[sp1$Site %in% c("site1", "site2"), ]
```

may need some slight alterations, didn't use a dummy set to check as not provided

edit: sp1$ required since not data.table

Answer (score 1):

I am no t sure if I understand what do you really want as output, but I suspect you want a dataframe for species == sp1 with data of the two sites.

If I am correct you should do the merge by species not by site, like as follow:

```
site.1.2 <- merge(site.1,site.2, by = "species")
```

If not, and you want to merge by site you should do :

```
site.1.2 <- merge(site.1,site.2, by = "site", all=T)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution:

`rbind(site.1,site.2)`